# looking to remove duplicates from an array with key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have duplicate values looks like as shown in below figure

[image]

I have used below code but its only giving the names like as `ashare1 guideline2`and i am looking for id as well.

please find the below code currently i have used

```
const optionMap0 = [
...new Set(libraryEquipment.map(e => e.equipmentSource.name)),
{
  id: '1d037be564c548eebe71db4e45e26cf7',
  name: 'None',
},
];
```

Could any one please suggest any idea on how to get distinct values from the above array of objects.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to an object, with the key as the name, and the value as the object itself, and then use Object.values() to get the objects.

```
const obj = {};
libraryEquipment.forEach(e => obj[e.equipmentSource.name] = e.equipmentSource);
const optionMap0 = Object.values(obj);
```

Unlike set, if you have more than one object with the same name, it will keep the last one. You can check before adding the object so it will use the first object with the same name, like so:

```
const obj = {};
libraryEquipment.forEach(e => { 
    if (!obj[e.equipmentSource.name]) 
        obj[e.equipmentSource.name] = e.equipmentSource'
});
const optionMap0 = Object.values(obj);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i would like to keep none as option to that `{
  id: '1d037be564c548eebe71db4e45e26cf7',
  name: 'None',
},`

Comment: Just like you did - `const optionMap0 = {...Object.values(obj), { id: '1d037be564c548eebe71db4e45e26cf7', name: 'None' }};`